# How to show only ids that have all selected set of values specific that id in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, relational-division

There are tables:

```
PRODUCT
|id
|name
|city

PART
|id
|name
|color
|weight
|city

SUPLIER
|id
|name
|rating
|city

SUPLIES
|sup_id
|part_id
|prod_id
|amount
```

Ex: Show id and name of products where Supplier(1) supply several parts of each part type from all parts supplied by that supplier. (Exercise was translated from another language).

There are partids are supplied by supplier 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT part_id FROM supplies JOIN parts ON part_id=parts.id WHERE sup_id=1;
```

Let's say they are: 1,2,4,6;

Also supplier 1 supply these products:

```
SELECT DISTINCT products.name FROM supplies JOIN products ON
sup_id=products.id WHERE sup_id=1;
```

Suppose they are 1,3,9;
Then I need to show only those products (with id=in(1,3,9)) for which all supplied part types are used (in other words, all of parts with id=in(1,2,4,6)).
So if for product with id=1 only some parts (for example parts with id=2 and 4) were used, then it must not be shown. Of course if I understand exercise correctly.

Strictly speaking that is what I don't know how to write.

EDIT:
To give some details there are some examples:

```
Supplier Part Product Amount
1        1    1       200
1        1    3       300
1        1    9       400
1        2    1       500
1        2    3       100
1        2    9       700
1        4    1       200
1        4    3       800
1        6    1       100
```

As in explanation above, only one product id must be shown: it is 1, because it used all supplied part types (1,2,4,6);

If we add one more record like this:

```
1        6    3       100
```

Then it changes output to 1 and 3. Because both use 1,2,4 and 6 parts.

If we add another one record:

```
1        5    9       1100
```

Then we shall have empty output. Because no one use all set of parts (1,2,4,5,6).

Hope this clarifies something.

Comment: I don't see a relationship between parts and products in your schema, except for what the supplier supplies. Does that mean that the products consist of parts as defined by the supplies? That seems a bit strange, because I could imagine that a supplies record is deleted when there is no more supply, but that does not change the relationship between a part and a product. I would in fact expect a separate table 'consists_of` with `part_id` and  `prod_id` fields.

Comment: it will be helpful if you can provide data for each table. As well as result output you would like to see. Please help us to help you.

Comment: The relation is shown in supplies table. So that means that we bought some amount of part for specified product.

Comment: @KashifQureshi hope my edit was helpful.

Comment: @trincot supplies table means the fact of buying some parts for some product. So shown parts not the all parts product consists from. No records will be deleted, there is just initial set of data which will never change. All changes in my edit, just to clarify exercise.

Comment: @user8574437 Still confused. So, if the data in it never changes, is your `supplies` table really a "how to build" table? I.e., does the example above mean that to build one example of _Product 3_ you need: 300 copies of _Part 1_, 100 of _Part 2_ and 800 of _Part 4_? Because its name (and the numbers involved) make it sound more like an _inventory_ table (which would change over time as you make things and get more supplies).  And having `city` against both `part` and `product` sounds "odd", as well.